# Error: FormatException - Unexpected end of input when receiving Bluetooth data in Flutter app

Tags: json, flutter, dart, format

I'm currently working on a Flutter app that receives data (an array of objects) from an ESP32 device via Bluetooth using the `flutter_bluetooth_serial` package. However, I keep encountering an error during the data receiving process. Although it doesn't affect the functionality of the app at the moment, I would like to understand the cause of the error.

When receiving the data, I have a data listening function named `_startListening()`. Here's the code snippet:

```dart
void _startListening() {
  _connection!.input!.listen((Uint8List data) {
    String jsonString = utf8.decode(data);
    List<dynamic> sensorData = json.decode(jsonString);
    debugPrint(jsonString); //Print utf8 decode output in console
    setState(() {
      _sensorData = sensorData;
    });
  });
}
```

The debug console output shows the received data as follows:

```dart
I/flutter ( 1972): [{"sensor":"heart-rate","value":73},{"sensor":"temperature","value":31.89999962},{"sensor":"pulse-oximeter","value":97.59999847}]
E/flutter ( 1972): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at line 2, character 1)
E/flutter ( 1972):
E/flutter ( 1972): ^
E/flutter ( 1972):
E/flutter ( 1972): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
E/flutter ( 1972): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:501:7)
E/flutter ( 1972): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:36:10)
E/flutter ( 1972): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
E/flutter ( 1972): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
E/flutter ( 1972): #5      _BluetoothDataScreenState._startListening.<anonymous closure>
blue_screen.dart:45
E/flutter ( 1972): #6      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1593:10)
E/flutter ( 1972): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter ( 1972): #8      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:515:14)
E/flutter ( 1972): #9      _PendingEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:620:11)
E/flutter ( 1972): #10     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:7)
E/flutter ( 1972): #11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 1972): #12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter ( 1972):
```

The error message I'm encountering is: `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at line 2, character 1)`. I believe this is due to incorrect JSON formatting, but I don't see anything wrong, I'm struggling to identify the exact cause and resolve the problem.

Could someone please assist me in understanding why this error occurs and guide me on resolving the incorrect JSON format issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `debugPrint(jsonString.length)` what do you see now?

Comment: The length keeps changing around 120 and 130 when it (new data) arrives. However, I have noticed that the error sometimes does not occur when the length of the data is 122, 124, or 131.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable to add SOLVED to your question title. If the answer you received below led you to a solution, you can accept it as correct, which tells people it was solved. If you solved it on your own and want to share that solution, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. For more information, see the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the console output and the modifications made to the `_startListening()` function, I have identified the issue causing the error. It appears that there is a byte array [13, 10] (representing newline characters '\r\n') sometimes sent by the ESP32 device, which was causing the error during JSON decoding.

To address this issue, I added a line of code to filter out the '\r\n' characters from the received data before performing the JSON decoding. Here's the modified `_startListening()` function:

```dart
void _startListening() {
  _connection!.input!.listen((Uint8List data) {
    String jsonString = utf8.decode(data);
    jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('\r\n', '');
    if (jsonString.isNotEmpty) {
      List<dynamic> sensorData = json.decode(jsonString);
      print(sensorData);
      setState(() {
        _sensorData = sensorData;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

After making this modification, the error no longer occurs, and everything works fine without any errors.